# google apps script push client variable to server

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Revised code to be correct and functional per utphx's answer.
In google apps script, I have the following basic code:

.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  return template.evaluate()
  .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
function getCellContents() {
  var contents = {};
  var ns = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1A7HaSpjPyJjUcDuQZXc8TqJ-h0Sb0qoUzoypjF5ePOo');
  var nt = ns.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  contents.value = nt.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  return contents;
}
function save(v){
  var ns = SpreadsheetApp.openById('%sheetid%');
  var nt = ns.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  nt.getRange(1, 1).setValue(v);
}
```

And .html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class='block result-display' id='results'>
</div>
<br />
<button id=add>Save</button>
</body>
</html>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(function() {
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(function(contents) {
$('#results').append('<input id="test" value="'+contents.value+'"></input>');
})
.getCellContents();
});



$('#add').click(function(){
  var i=document.getElementById('test').value;
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function() {
  })
  .save(i);
});
</script>
```

.getCellContents correctly pulls and displays the value I want in a changeable input element.
My issue is with .save which I want to be able to change the  number, click the "Save" button and have the input value save to the spreadsheet. .setValue edits the data, I just can't figure out how to access the input's value from the server for it to correctly change the data - just erases the data currently because it doesn't recognize var i.

*note, "%sheetid%" is a place-holder for the question, I'm using the correct id in my file, and "var i=$('#test').value;" was left only for show to help explain what I'm looking for - can't declare client-side and use server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var i=document.getElementById('test').value
```

Comment: Of course, the first time I actually use jquery, there's a section that won't function with it...thanks utphx! Works perfectly now and updated my code.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark above.